# Using clamp_ip() to keep a sprite within the window

Tags: python, window, pygame, sprite

I'm trying to use `clamp_ip()` to keep my sprite on the screen that is 600 x 315 but it doesn't seem to work.

```
ship = pygame.image.load("ship.png")
ship_top = screen.get_width() - ship.get_width()
ship_left = screen.get_height()/2 - ship.get_height()/2

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        ship_left = ship_left - 6
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        ship_left = ship_left + 6

    screen.blit(back, (x,0))
    screen.blit(back2,(x-screenWidth,0))
    screen.blit(ship, (ship_top, ship_left))

    screen_rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (600, 315))

    def moveme(ship,ship_top,ship_left):
       ship.rect.move_ip((ship_top,ship_left))
       ship.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working". Please include **full** tracebacks (if they exist).

Comment: A wrote an answer the last time you posted this question, but you deleted it literally 2 seconds before I hit the *post your answer*-button :-(

Answer (score 0):

You never call `moveme`; instead of using rectangles you directly operate on the *unclamped* variable `ship_left`.

Answer (score 0):

To use `clamp_ip`, you have to work with a `Rect`:

```
ship = pygame.image.load("ship.png")
ship_top = screen.get_width() - ship.get_width()
ship_left = screen.get_height()/2 - ship.get_height()/2
ship_r = ship.get_rect(top=ship_top, left=ship_left)
```

then you can use the `Rect` methods in your main loop:

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    ship_r.move_ip(-6, 0)
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    ship_r.move_ip(6, 0)

ship_r.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

screen.blit(back, (x,0))
screen.blit(back2,(x-screenWidth,0))
screen.blit(ship, ship_r)
```